# jaxb - add elements to list (maven-plugin)

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb

I generated my classes with jaxb and now I need to populate some list. What's the best way to do that?

pom.xml:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                    <packageName>be.structure</packageName>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated/java</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The generated class where the list is located:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "configuration", propOrder = {
"professions"
})
public class Configuration {

protected List<Profession> professions;

public List<Profession> getProfessions() {
    if (professions == null) {
        professions = new ArrayList<Profession>();
    }
    return this.professions;
    }
}
```

but as you can see there is no "addProfession" or "setProfessions()" or something. I know there is a way, but I can't really remember it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getProfessions().add(profession)` should do the trick if the underlying list is mutable, but normally you wouldn't change the contents of JAX-instances since JAXB populates the objects for you based on the XML data it is read from - if you change that lists, its no representation of the XML anymore.

Comment: that was it indeed.. lol ^^. I do it this way because it's a very particular business.

Comment: "normally you wouldn't change the contents of JAX-instances" - that doesn't make sense. Of course you do change JAXB model beans to build a model which you then marshal to XML. And it's also perfectly legal to unmarshal a document, modify the model and then marshal the modified model.